# org-mode cannot find pdflatex using Mac OS

Tags: org-mode, org-export, osx

When I try to export an `org` file to `pdf` using `C-c C-e l o` I get the following message:

```
Saving file /Users/user/tmp/test.tex...
Wrote /Users/user/tmp/test.tex
Processing LaTeX file ./test.tex...
/bin/bash: pdflatex: command not found [3 times]
org-latex-compile: PDF file ./test.pdf wasn't produced
```

This happens when I open emacs by clicking on the icon that can be found in `/Applications`. However, if I open emacs from the command line:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
```

I can export the `org` file without any problem. It seems like in both cases the same init file is loaded and I fail to understand the problem. Any ideas?

NB: `version` returns:

```
GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21) of 2014-10-21 on builder10-9.porkrind.org
```

and `org-version` returns:

```
Org-mode version 8.2.10 (8.2.10-21-ga712ce-elpaplus @ /Users/drorata/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20141201/)
```

Finally, I'm using OS X 10.10.

### The `$PATH`:

I tried to include either `(add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/texbin/pdflatex")` or `(add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/texbin")` in my `.emacs` but this didn't help.

Comment: Something's up with your `$PATH`. Use `which pdflatex` from the terminal to find
where the program is. As a work around, you can then add this directory to
Emacs' path with `(add-to-list 'exec-path "/path/to/file")`

Comment: @nanny: see my update

Comment: I would try the path (i.e., a directory) instead of the file / executable itself.  Note, you can also change the environmental path:  `(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/texbin"))`

Comment: @lawlist: I tried both, and it didn't help.

Comment: What does `M-! which pdflatex RET` echo?

Comment: Does this link help?:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163849/mavericks-upgrade-screwed-up-my-pdflatex-command-not-found  Seems upgrading the OS wipes out sym-links.

Comment: @nanny: it returns: `(Shell command failed with code 1 and no output)`

Comment: @lawlist: I do have the sym-link `/usr/texbin/pdflatex`

Answer (score 5):

Two hints helped me solve the issue:

1. `$PATH` and
2. codename *Mavericks*

It seems like the problem is indeed related to the path, and the way around it is:

```
(defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
  "Sets the exec-path to the same value used by the user shell"
  (let ((path-from-shell
         (replace-regexp-in-string
          "[[:space:]\n]*$" ""
          (shell-command-to-string "$SHELL -l -c 'echo $PATH'"))))
    (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
    (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))

;; call function now
(set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH)
```

Taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/bradleywright/2046593) and linked to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22158330/671013).

**The question why there is a different behaviour between the two emacs opening methods remains unanswered.**

Comment: There is now a package for this `exec-path-from-shell`.  The difference in the situations is the environment when the command is called.  The PATH variable is often modified by the shell when in a terminal from the default in the background system.